# How to estimate size of a Jpeg file before saving it with a certain quality factor?

Tags: jpeg

I'v got a bitmap 24bits, I am writing application in c++, MFC,
I am using libjpeg for encoding the bitmap into jpeg file 24bits.

When this bitmap's width is M, and height is N.

How to estimate jpeg file size before saving it with certain quality factor N (0-100).

Is it possible to do this?

For example.
I want to implement a slide bar, which represent save a current bitmap with certain quality factor N.
A label is beside it. shows the approximate file size when decode the bitmap with this quality factor.
When user move the slide bar. He can have a approximate preview of  the filesize of the tobe saved jpeg file.

Comment: How long does it take to save out a JPG? Can you "save" it into memory (perhaps in another thread) and then get its size from that? If it's really quick, you can probably do the whole process, but just don't write anything to disk. At least for small images. For larger ones, guesstimate (can't help you there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In libjpeg, you can write a custom destination manager that doesn't actually call `fwrite`, but just counts the number of bytes written.

Start with the stdio destination manager in jdatadst.c, and have a look at the documentation in libjpeg.doc.

Your `init_destination` and `term_destination` methods will be very minimal (just alloc/dealloc), and your `empty_output_buffer` method will do the actual counting. Once you have completed the JPEG writing, you'll have to read the count value out of your custom structure. Make sure you do this before `term_destination` is called.

Comment: Many thanks Adam. I see. I am using FreeImage lib which is based on libjpeg , It have build-in API. I will use it

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the compression you are using and to be more specific how many bits per color pixel are you using.

The quality factor wont help you here as a quality factor of 100 can range (in most cases) from 6 bits per color pixel to ~10 bits per color pixel, maybe even more (Not sure).

so once you know that its really straight forward from there..

Comment: I want to save it as 24bits jpeg file

Comment: what you should be most interested in is the compression ratio and not the bit depth of the image. in other words mostly all images nowadays uses a 24 bit depth, translated into R = 8bits, G = 8 bits and B = 8 bits (RGB). now to calculate an image size first you'll need the size in Mega pixels MP which is basically the width multiplied by the height of the image. then to get the size in bytes you'll multiply the size in MP by the bit depth and divide by 8.. in your case that is (N * M * 24)/8. This will give you the raw size of the image which is the same as that of a raw BMP.

Comment: You'll have to divide that by the compression ratio. for example if your compression ration is 4:1 this means that you'll divide by 4 making the equation looks like this:

((N * M * 24)/8)/4

Comment: and bare in mind that JPEG conversion is not lossless so there has to be a conversion somewhere and its probably determined by the quality factor.

Comment: Which is why you estimate using sub sampling from the Component Information as I described which also reveals the bits per component.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Sub Sampling Factor this can be estimated. That information comes from the start of frame marker.

In the same marker right before the width and height so is the bit depth.

If you let

```
int subSampleFactorH = 2, subSampleFactorV = 1;
```

Then

`int totalImageBytes = (Image.Width / subSampleFactorH)  * (Image.Height / subSampleFactorV);`

Then you can also optionally add more bytes to account for container data also.

`int totalBytes = totalImageBytes + someConstantOverhead;`